# Проблема с перезапуском Activity

Tags: activity, android

Всем привет. Проблема следующая: имеется приложение, простой таймер ЧЧ:ММ:СС и кнопка "Запустить", я нажимаю эту кнопку, она меняет текст на "Остановить" и таймер начинает тикать, сворачиваю и разворачиваю приложение - таймер по нулям, на кнопке текст "Запустить", на нажатия кнопка не реагирует. Этот баг для андроидов от 4 версии, на старых платформах все работает. 
Кто-нибудь знает, в чем проблема и куда копать?
Вот код главной активити:

```
package dev.svyat.justtimer;
import java.util.Date;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

TextView showTime;
Button goStopButton;
String timeString;
int secondCounter, minuteCounter, hourCounter;
Date date;
Thread timerThread;
boolean continueThread;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    showTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.time);
    goStopButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.goButton);
    secondCounter = 0;
    minuteCounter = 0;
    hourCounter = 0;
    timeString = (String.valueOf(hourCounter) + ":" 
            + String.valueOf(minuteCounter) + ":" + String.valueOf(secondCounter));
    showTime.setText(timeString);
}

public void goButtonClick(View v){
    if(goStopButton.getText().equals("Запустить")){
        goStopButton.setText("Остановить");
        date=new Date();
        continueThread = true;
        timeUpdate();
    }
    else{
        goStopButton.setText("Запустить");
        continueThread = false;
    }
}

Handler mHandlerUpdateTime = new Handler();
Handler mHandlerNullTime = new Handler();

public void timeUpdate()
{
    timerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(continueThread){
                Date newDate = new Date();
                if(((newDate.getTime()) - date.getTime()) > 1000){
                    secondCounter = secondCounter+1;
                    mHandlerUpdateTime.post(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            timeString = (String.valueOf(hourCounter) + ":" 
                        + String.valueOf(minuteCounter) + ":" + String.valueOf(secondCounter));
                            showTime.setText(timeString);
                            Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Время = " + timeString);
                        }
                    });
                //    System.out.println("Inside the Theread ..."+secondCounter);
                    if(secondCounter > 59){
                        minuteCounter = minuteCounter + 1;
                        mHandlerUpdateTime.post(new Runnable(){
                            @Override
                            public void run(){
                                timeString = (String.valueOf(hourCounter) + ":" 
                            + String.valueOf(minuteCounter) + ":" + String.valueOf(secondCounter));
                                showTime.setText(timeString);
                                Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Время = " + timeString);
                            }
                        });
                        secondCounter = 0;
                        if(minuteCounter > 59){
                            hourCounter = hourCounter + 1;
                            mHandlerUpdateTime.post(new Runnable(){
                                @Override
                                public void run(){
                                    timeString = (String.valueOf(hourCounter) + ":" 
                                + String.valueOf(minuteCounter) + ":" + String.valueOf(secondCounter));
                                    showTime.setText(timeString);
                                    Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Время = " + timeString);
                                }
                            });
                            minuteCounter = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
                Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Время = " + String.valueOf(hourCounter) + ":" 
                        + String.valueOf(minuteCounter) + ":" + String.valueOf(secondCounter));
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){

                    }
        }
        }
            });
    timerThread.setPriority(10);
    timerThread.start();
};
```

}

Comment: Какая именно часть кода вас интересует?
Вычисления провожу в AsyncTask, в методе doInBackground сами вычисления, затем publishProgress результатов и в методе onProgressUpdate присваиваю значение результатов таймеру.
Чтобы не показаться профаном, скажу следующее - вывожу в логи вычисления значений таймера и текст таймера. По логам - с вычислениями и таймером все в порядке, то есть в логах они тикают и текст таймера меняется, даже когда я сворачиваю-разворачиваю приложение. Но почему-то на активити после сворачивания-разворачивания таймер показывает нули, а по логам - должен тикать дальше.

Comment: Большая проблема использования AsyncTask - слабая связанность с жизненным циклом Activity.
При сворачивании-разворачивании у вас на экране отображается новый Activity instance, в то время, как AsyncTask пытается обновлять старую Activity.

Comment: На мой взгляд, простейшим решением данной проблемы будет вынос кода таймера в Thread, которому (в конструкторе, например) будет передаваться Handler для манипуляций с UI. Thread отлично сериализуется и восстанавливается в onSaveInstanceState/onCreate. Единственное, надо будет обязательно обновлять поле потока, хранящее Handler при каждом восстановлении в onCreate. Ну и, разумеется, пометить это поле как transient.

Comment: Вот вопрос - почему же в логах все нормально отображается? Я беру текст из TextView, в котором вывожу время, и в логах все отображается правильно. А вот в активити нули.

Comment: Потому, что вы получаете текст из TextView предыдущего instance Activity, его же и обновляете, а на экране отображается новый экземпляр Activity с, соответственно, другим экземпляром TextView.

Вообще, странно, что с Thread'ом у вас не заработало, мне даже стало интересно посмотреть. Если есть желание/возможность, можете предоставить доступ к коду (или его части), сегодня вечерком отпишусь что там не так.

Comment: Я прослеживал методы, которые вызываются Activity при сворачивании-разворачивании. Через логи, естественно. Последний метод - onStop(). По документации - Activity уничтожается. После onStop() вызывается метод onRestart().
В поисках этой проблемы, я вчера перелопатил сайт developer.android.com и там было сказано, что потоки лучше использовать для коротких задач - быстро что-то посчитать и т.д.
У меня задача длинная, для длинных задач настоятельно рекомендуют использовать сервисы. Сейчас я как раз пишу сервис, как отлажу - отпишусь о результатах.

Comment: То, что вы написали по поводу Activity - подтвердилось.
Вернулся к своей старой версии, где мой таймер работал в Thread. Обновляю пользовательский интерфейс с помощью Handler'ов, все работает хорошо до сворачивания-разворачивания.
По отладке потока - даже при свернутом приложении поток продолжает свою работу, и при разворачивании окна приложения в логах идет отсчет времени, а на Activity он не идет.
Как я понимаю, мне обратиться к заново созданной Activity и ее компонентам?

Comment: При восстановлении экземпляра Thread (onCreate activity, то бишь) надо потоку указать новую activity и/или обновить Handler.

Answer (score 3):

Это не баг, необходимо сохранять и восстанавливать состояние `Activity`, `onSaveInstanceState` вам в помощь.
Так же, настоятельно рекомендую проштудировать документацию по жизненному циклу [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), будет полезно.

Comment: Просто сохранять не получится - таймер то наверное должен работать, пока пользователь свернул приложение?

Тут нужен сервис.

Comment: Если бы все было так просто. onSavedInstance я использовал, он просто возвращает сохраненное значение Activity, а мне надо чтобы таймер дальше тикал, в этом-то и вся проблема. С onSavedInstance я просто получаю Activity с застывшим таймером. 
Документацию я уже проштудировал и сайт developer.google.com я тоже облазил, поэтому и пишу тут.
Насчет сервиса я тоже думал, но понимаете - в ранних версиях мой код работает, почему же он не работает в поздних? К тому же сервис, насколько мне известно, не взаимодействует с пользовательским интерфейсом.

Comment: У меня в layout-файле есть текстовое поле:

    <TextView
    android:id = "@+id/time"
    ...
    />

В методе onCreate я делаю следующее:

    TextView myTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.time);

Потом вывожу в логи текст, который находится в myTime в процессе работы приложения. По логам все работает - я запускаю таймер, сворачиваю-разворачиваю, элемент myTime принимает правильные значения, но при перезапуске Activity не отображает их. 
Без метода onSavedInstance таймер обнуляется, с onSavedInstance сохраняет значения и не тикает.
Напомню, что в версиях андроид до 4 версии все работает.

Comment: А каких решений вы ожидали, не удосужившись даже показать код? Лично у меня с телепатией проблемы, посему предполагаю у вопрошающего наиболее распространённые ошибки/проблемы. Соответственно и отвечаю.

>> за 5,5 лет программирования я первый раз сюда зашел, что уже говорит само за себя
Это вовсе ни о чём не говорит.

Comment: Поверьте, я уже столько раз сталкивался с заявлениями "я нашёл баг", "андроид неправильно работает", когда человек не в состоянии прочитать первые же строки документации, что уже научился не замечать подобные высказывания. :)

Ну и прошу прощения, если мой шаблонный подход вас оскорбил.

Comment: Итак, очков уважения у меня мало, не могу написать решение своего вопроса, но я его уже нашел. У меня в примере для часов, минут и секунд 3 отдельных текстовых поля, которое было прописано в activity_main.xml. Я сделал одно текстовое поле, затем в программе из полученных часов, минут и секунд формировал строку и значение строки вставлял в текстовое поле.
И у меня все заработало. Сохранение/Восстановление окна оказалось тут ни при чем.